# Print array inside array using smarty template engine

Tags: php, templates, foreach, smarty

I am having one array like this. The tree structure of this array is very big.  I want to print the array using the smarty tags in the html file.  I am using this code to do this,

Assigned like this in PHP file, `$smarty->assign("arrForumData", $arrForumData);`

In HTML File like this for single dimension array.

```
{foreach item=foo from=$arrForumData}
{$foo.question}
{$foo.name} etc...
{/foreach}
```

I dont know how to print array which is like below in smarty.  Please guide me how to print multidimension array's in smarty.  Hope my question is clear.  thanks in advance.

[image: ARRAY]

Comment: Please provide an example of what you would like accomplished. It's not clear whether you want to print the whole array structure, or just the entries containing a name and question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact answer.  Working perfect for me.

```
{foreach name=outer item=v from=$arrForumData}
        {$v[0].question_id}
        {$v[0].project_id}
        {$v[0].name}
        {$v[0].email}
        {$v[0].question}
        {$v[0].created_on}

      {foreach key=key item=item from=$v[1]}
        {$item.aQId}
        {$item.aAns}
        {$item.aName}
        {$item.aEmail}
        {$item.aDate}
      {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
{foreach key=key item=item from=$arrForumData}
  {if $item|@is_array}
    {foreach key=inner_key item=inner_item from=$arrForumData[$key]}
      {if $inner_item|@is_array}
        {foreach key=innermost_key item=innermost_item from=$arrForumData[$key][$inner_key]}
            {$innermost_item.aQId}
            {$innermost_item.aAns}
            {$innermost_item.aName}
            {$innermost_item.aEmail}
            {$innermost_item.aDate}
        {/foreach}
      {else}
        {$inner_item.question_id}
        {$inner_item.project_id}
        {$inner_item.name}
        {$inner_item.email}
        {$inner_item.question}
        {$inner_item.created_on}
      {/if} 
    {/foreach}
 {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Why not? Do you need someone to give you a complete written solution to your problem?